# Convertir dato de un spinner a String

Tags: java, android

¿Cómo puedo convertir los datos de un `Spinner` a un `String`?

```
Spinner cur = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
  Spinner cur = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerp);
  String text =  cur.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331854/how-to-get-spinner-selected-item-value-to-string

Comment: creo que `Text` deberia ir en minusculas al no ser el nombre de una clase

Comment: "Text" debe ser una variable no un tipo! :(

Comment: Es una variable solo que al estar en mayúscula lo tomo como tipo!

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el dato seleccionado dentro de un `Spinner`:

```
Spinner cur = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerp);
String textoElementoSeleccionado = cur.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

o

```
String textoElementoSeleccionado = (String)cur.getSelectedItem();
```

---

Para obtener todos los elementos de un `Spinner`:

```
      List<String> textosSpinner = new ArrayList<String>();    

      for (int i = 0; i < listViewDatos.getChildCount(); i++) {

        View listItem = listViewDatos.getChildAt(i);

        Spinner cur = (Spinner) listItem.findViewById(R.id.spinnerp);

        //Obtiene texto.
        String selection = cur.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //agrega textos a List.
        textosSpinner.add(selection);
      }
```